# Change in view when assigning a column to original df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=list('abc'))

p = df['a']
p._is_view  # True
df.a = 0

p == df.a  # why FALSE?
```

`p` is view of `df` but why is the change in `df` not visible in `p`?

In other hand:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=list('abc'))

p = df['a']
p._is_view  # True
df.loc[:, 'a'] = 0

p == df.a  # TRUE
```

it works as I expected.

My question: Why are the results different between this two methods?

The views in pandas are mysterious and difficult to understand...

Comment: I guess when `pandas` sees `df.a=0` it just creates whole new `pd.Series` (optimalization?), but `df.loc[:,'a']=0` it replaces values in this `pd.Series` so `p` is changed too. Note, if you do `df.a[:] = 0` values in `p` are changed too.

Answer (score 2):

I think the behaviour you describe aligns with pandas' *expectations*.

Quoting the [release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/index.html) of `1.3.0` :

> 1. [**Never** operate inplace when setting `frame[keys] = values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#never-operate-inplace-when-setting-frame-keys-values)
> 2. [**Try** operating inplace when setting values with `loc` and `iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#try-operating-inplace-when-setting-values-with-loc-and-iloc)

Point 1 explains why `p == df.a` returns a boolean `False` Series in the first example and point 2 verifies the `True` Series of the second.

```
import numpy as np

# 1st example
np.shares_memory(df["a"], p) # False

# 2nd example
np.shares_memory(df["a"], p) # True
```

Comment: Note that this is **always** true only for version 2+ of Pandas. In previous versions it's true only if the dtype of the column remains the same when setting with `.loc`; if the dtype is different (like `df.loc[:, 'a'] = 'a'`), a new column will be created so the equality would return `False`.